# orgchart splitting into three, and displaying Id's on the chart

Tags: orgchart, google-visualization

Here's what my chart displays:

[image]

Here's my Position tables:

[My position table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OYZk.png)

cant really seem to figure out whats the problem.

-Ive got a button and a dropdown, when an item is selected from the dropdown and button is selected an orgchart must be displayed. The chart displays but the problems are:

-orgchart splitting into three charts

-And it keeps showing some Id's

-here's my code:

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $("#btnGetOrganogram").on('click', function (e) {
            debugger
            $ddlDepOrgano = $('[id$="ddlDepOrgano"]').val();
            if ($ddlDepOrgano != "") {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/services/eleaveService.asmx/GetChartData',
                    data: "{'depid':'" + $ddlDepOrgano + "'}",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess_getOrgData,
                    error: OnErrorCall_getOrgData
                });

                function OnSuccess_getOrgData(repo) {

                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

                    var response = repo.d;
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        var row = new Array();
                        var Pos_Name = response[i].Pos_Name;
                        var Pos_Level = response[i].Pos_Level;
                        var Emp_Name = response[i].Emp_Name;
                        var Pos_ID = response[i].Pos_ID;
                        var Emp_ID = response[i].Emp_ID;
                        data.addRows([[{
                            v: Emp_ID,
                            f: Pos_Name
                        }, Pos_Level, Emp_Name]]);

                    }

                    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data,{ allowHtml: true });
                }

                function OnErrorCall_getOrgData() {
                    console.log("something went wrong ");
                }
            } else {
                bootbox.alert("Invalid Department Name please try again.");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

Comment: @WhiteHat :I've just edited my post and added an image of my Positions table.I'm using two tables, one being the tbl_Position and secondly tbl_Employee which contains Pos_ID as a foreign key in the tbl_Employee

Answer (score 0):

according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#data-format), *Column 1* should be the ID of the manager, which is used to build the tree...

> Column 1 - [optional] The ID of the parent node. This should be the unformatted value from column 0 of another row. Leave unspecified for a root node.

looking at the data table image posted, this should be in column --> `Mngr_ID`

as such, recommend the following changes when loading the data...

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var row = new Array();
    var Pos_Name = response[i].Pos_Name;
    var Emp_Name = response[i].Emp_Name;
    var Emp_ID = response[i].Emp_ID;
    var Mngr_ID = response[i].Mngr_ID;
    data.addRow([
      {
        v: Emp_ID,
        f: Pos_Name
      },
      Mngr_ID,
      Emp_Name
    ]);
}
```

Comment: well i managed to display a structured organogram with the input you gave me, the minor problem i experienced is that it doesnt display all the positions. if the "Managing position" has five "Sub positions", it only shows one of the five "Sub positions" under the "Managing position"

Comment: Instead of showing all five "Sub Positions" that are under the "Managing Position" @WhiteHat

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hofr.png here's what the orgchart displays. And here's my table structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5OGi.png @WhiteHat